# Will this add the entity to the database twice?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables, SR_Leagues and SR_Programs. SR_Programs has a one to many relationship with SR_Leagues.

I have the following code using Entity Framework:

```
var newProgram = new SR_Programs
{
    // Set Properties
    Leagues = new List<SR_Leagues>()
};

ctx.SR_Programs.Add(newProgram);

SR_Leagues tmpLeague = new SR_Leagues
{
     // Set properties
};
```

Then this is the part I am asking about:

```
ctx.SR_Leagues.Add(tmpLeague);

if (newProgram.Leagues != null)
{
    newProgram.Leagues.Add(tmpLeague);
}
```

Then I close the DB context

```
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Will this add the `tmpLeague` entity to the database twice? Once attached to the `newProgram` and once added to the `SR_Leagues` table?

Or will EF know that it is the same entity because of the relationship between the two?

Comment: Where did newProgram come from?

Comment: @CaiusJard the newProgram is added to ctx.SR_Programs just before the code I posted. Both calls are in the same DB context and ctx.SaveChanges() has not been called yet. If I need more clarification let me know and I will edit my question

Comment: @CaiusJard I updated my question

Comment: Redundant `if (newProgram.Leagues != null)`; `newProgram.Leagues` is never null in this code

Comment: You don't need to micromanage EF to this degree; if you create a Program, then add a League to it, you don't also need to add the League to the context Leagues; it will save when you add the Program and SaveChanges

Comment: I totally agree about the unneeded null check and micromanaging EF, I am debugging this code of a legacy system and came across these statements. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this add the tmpLeague entity to the database twice?

No, but you don't need to do it

> Or will EF know that it is the same entity because of the relationship between the two?

Yes, but you don't need to do it

```
var newProgram = new SR_Programs
{
    // Set Properties
    Leagues = new List<SR_Leagues>()
};

ctx.SR_Programs.Add(newProgram);

newProgram.Leagues.Add(new SR_Leagues
{
     // Set properties
});


await context.SaveChangesAsync()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to call

```
ctx.SR_Leagues.Add(tmpLeague);
```

when

```
newProgram.Leagues.Add(tmpLeague);
```

is being called. 
They both set the State tracking property of `SR_Leagues` object to Added. 
Entity framework will issue only one insert statement related to this object.